# Cannot use sudo from GUI terminal emulator only

Tags: sudo, xterm

I just followed the directions here: https://blog.kumina.nl/2010/07/two-factor-luks-using-ubuntu/ for using a smart card to unlock my luks drive on boot. I changed things slightly since the install was completed already, but it was essentially the same process/result.

Now, it works fine, but I cannot use sudo from terminal emulators in the GUI. I have two-factor auth set up. It will ask for the first pam_module, but it will not ask for my password via pam_unix. I've tried reverting pam back to original settings, and no luck.

Interestingly, I can use sudo just fine from TTY1-6. Polkit also allows me to elevate privileges in the GUI. I found an old Ubuntu forums post I made about this exact issue in 2013 that got no responses, but I seem to remember figuring it out as having something to do with the change in luks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my own problem. Found this in the comments on the linked page:

> harningt says:     01/11/2013 at 06:25
>
> Got this setup, awesome  However, I had to make some modifications
>   since creating a tty is breaks things in Ubuntu 13.10
>
> I edited the decrypt_luks.sh file and added –no-tty and dropped the
>   tty setup code. And things work great

Making that little change solved my problem! Hope this helps anyone else in the same boat.